# Concerns on lazy evaluation and infinite data structures

Tags: functional-programming, haskell, evaluation

I am trying to learn how lazy evaluation works because I'm going to <s>implement</s> *try* to implement it in the programming language I'm developing (I know it isn't the best thing to do (to try to implement something you don't even understand) but it's making for a good extensive lesson through the world of functional languages and the like), so I was reading the paper A Gentle Introduction to Haskell.

Soon I encountered the paragraph on the non-strictness of Haskell functions and the possibility of creating teorethically infinite data structures, as shown in this example:

```
numsfrom n = 1 : numsfrom (n + 1)

squares = map (^ 2) (numsfrom 0)
```

Now, `take 5 squares` would return `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]`, right? Well, my problem is understanding *how* it would do it.

First things first, this is what I understood of lazy evaluation:

```
lazy = lambda x, y: x or y
```

Assuming Python was non-strict, if I passed to `lazy` `1` and `5 ** 1000000` the second parameter would not get evaluated, but it would get evaluated if I passed `False` as the first argument, because `or` would then have requested it.

So when calling `take 5 squares`, `squares` has to be evaluated: `map` is called with `(^ 2)` and `(numsfrom 0)` as the arguments; But since `map` uses it's second argument, `numsfrom 0` will be evaluated, starting an infinite loop.

I cannot understand how would `map` return if it's evaluating an infinite loop, and what it would return. Can someone please explain me it?

Comment: [__Chapter 4.2 in SICP__](http://sarabander.github.io/sicp/html/index.xhtml#toc-Metalinguistic-Abstraction) discusses implementing lazy evaluation, lazy streams, non-deterministic search and other related topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the fundamental concept absolutely correct. The problem is that you're not applying it on a large enough scale.

In Haskell, *everything* (or close enough for the purposes of this question and answer) behaves the way that `or` does in Python (and many, many languages). Including, say, "Get me the next element of the list".

So when you call `numsfrom`, in fact, the result of `numsfrom` is not created immediately and returned. It is produced as needed on an element-by-element basis. The function `numsfrom` can be partially evaluated, piece by piece, as the result is needed. Since `map` doesn't ask for an infinite number of elements, there is no infinite looping going on. This is similar to iterators I believe in Python.

As a side note, shouldn't `numsfrom` be `numsfrom n = n : numsfrom (n + 1)`? Seems to me like your `numsfrom` will produce an infinite list of `1`s.

Comment: The side note's right thanks. But could you explain step by step what's going on when I first define `squares` (what's stored as `squares`? A thunk?), and what steps take place when `take 5 squares` is executed?

Comment: Oh wait. I think I got it. The return of `n : numsfrom (1 + n)` is `[n, thunk(numsfrom (1 + n))]`, not `[n, resultof numsfrom (1 + n)]`. This is why an infinite loop isn't started and it also explains how can it `take` a limited number of an infinite list, because `map f (x : xs)` returns `[f x, thunk(map f xs)]`, not `[f x, map f xs]`. Wonderful!

Answer (score 3):

The trick is that any data constructor in Haskell is lazy (unless annotated [otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/993112/1333025)). In your case, the list constructor

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

So when you evaluate `take 5 squares` (remember Haskell lists are linked lists), you evaluate the first five `(:)` constructors, but the rest is kept as an unevaluated thunk.